# WordPress Multisite with HTML template as Root

Tags: multisite, html

Sorry about the title, I couldn't think of a good one. Would it be possible to have a WordPress Multisite setup with a HTML landing page as the frontend and just have the backend of WordPress accessible. The frontend would also have to display Sign Up/Login buttons and then when the user signs in have it display their profile picture and name in place of the Sign Up/Login buttons.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, quick and dirty just create a new page template, set it as the home page. Then in your page template copy the signup code from `wp-signup.php` into the page template